# Thanksgiving 5k special achievement not showing up

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

I completed my 5k on Thanksgiving day. The activity is visible in both my Activity app and in the Health app. But the special achievement never showed up. Not the end of the world, but it does kind of suck. Anybody else experiencing this or have a solution?

More info about the award [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/11/21/apple-challenges-u-s-apple-watch-owners-to-bag-a-special-thanksgiving-day-activity-achievement/).

[image]

Comment: Is this an achievement in the activity app? As far as I know, Apple hasn't put any achievements like that in the app.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yep; see here: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/11/21/apple-challenges-u-s-apple-watch-owners-to-bag-a-special-thanksgiving-day-activity-achievement/

Comment: Are you in the US?

Comment: @patrix Yes, I'm in the US. I contacted Apple support about this, and they suggested un-pairing and re-pairing the watch, which did not help.